# erb without rails helpers

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra, erb

I'm switching a python app to ruby and need to implement erb into the html and am clueless as to how to implement some of the most basic things.  It seems like everything that I look up basically recommends using rails helpers that aren't available to me.  I'm trying to get the below line to work.  I figured anything in the loop would get interpolated, but my links aren't working.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 <% for employee in @employees %>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 employee">
            <a style="text-align:center;" href="/employee/#{employee.id}" class="thumbnail">
              <% if !employee.filename? %>  
              <img src='#{settings.employee_image_url}'> 
              <% else %>
              <img src='#{settings.no_image_url}'>
              <% end %>
```

Comment: Also, what does `settings` look like? Did you try p'ing it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the link and image tags into separate methods.  That contain the strings.  so..

```
def tag_string 
"<a style='text-align:center;' href='/employee/#{employee.id}' class='thumbnail'>"
end
```

and call it in the view like this:

```
<%= tag_string %>
```

Basically, all you have to do is make whatever tag you're interpolating into a string with double quotes and put the erb tags on either side.  This is the answer I wish I would've found with googling.

Answer (score 1):

The follow should fix the issue.

```
<img src="<%= settings.no_image_url %>">
```

String Interpolation is only executed by Ruby, "#{settings.no_image_url}" is not a Ruby string in the context that you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes here `'#{settings.employee_image_url}'` instead of single quotes. So `"#{settings.employee_image_url}"`

Comment: thanks, I actually ended up taking those out into methods in the app file and putting double quotes around them there, then putting the method between erb tags in the view.  Any thoughts on why the anchor tag isn't interpolating?  I thought if it was in a loop, it would already know it's erb.

Comment: Should get interpolated if its erb. What do you see in your browser when you hover over the link?

Comment: I moved that into a seperate method too.  It effectively does this:

<%= "<a style='text-align:center;' href='/employee/#{employee.id}' class='thumbnail'>" %>

Basically, all you have to do is make whatever tag you're interpolating in to a string with double quotes and put the erb tags on either side.